# Magento catalog price rules

Tags: catalog-price-rules

I have configured magento with only catalogus price rules, no shopping cart price rules exist.

The catalogus price rules define different percentage discount for different categories, for different user groups. All price rules say 'stop further processing'.

Now I have a conflict in the price calculations in shopping cart when adding multiple products.

For example:

I add a product (1) which has catalog price rule A, price is fine
I add a product (2) which has catalog price rule B, price is wrong. The discount from catalog price rule A is applied (because product (1) has price rule A).
When I remove product (1) from shopping cart, the price for product (2) is adjusted to the correct price
Demonstrated in the following screenshots: http://www.phpworks.nl/magento-catalog-price-rules.png

Now my question is: is this behaviour a bug in magento ? Catalog price rules should be calculated per product, not per shopping cart, if im right ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you've enabled the option, "Stop Further Rules Processing"

So if the first rule applies, it will never reach the second rule..

Comment: I have set Stop Further Rules Processing to Yes, still same behaviour.